# why are left joins limiting my result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The result set of my query is approximately 60k rows:

```
SELECT f.client_id,
       f.SECTION_A,
       Month(f.received_date) Month,
       Count(*)               Count
FROM   MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV..F_ACCESSION_DAILY f
       LEFT JOIN salesdwh..TestPractices t
         ON F.CLIENT_ID = t.ClientID
WHERE  t.ClientID IS NULL
       AND Month(f.received_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 11
       AND Year(f.received_date) = 2012
GROUP  BY f.SECTION_A,
          Month(f.received_date),
          f.client_id
```

however when i add 2 left joins, it is limiting it to 56k rows!

```
SELECT f.client_id,
       f.SECTION_A,
       Month(f.received_date) Month,
       Count(*)               Count,
       s.SALES_REP_NAME,
       s.REGION_NAME
FROM   MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV..F_ACCESSION_DAILY f
       LEFT JOIN salesdwh..TestPractices t
         ON F.CLIENT_ID = t.ClientID
       LEFT JOIN MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV..D_CLIENT d
         ON d.CLIENT_ID = f.CLIENT_ID
       LEFT JOIN MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV..D_SALES_HIERARCHY s
         ON s.SUB_TERRITORY_NBR = d.SUB_TERRITORY_NBR
WHERE  t.ClientID IS NULL
       AND Month(f.received_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 11
       AND Year(f.received_date) = 2012
       AND d.REC_ACTIVE_FLG = 1
       AND s.REC_ACTIVE_FLG = 1
GROUP  BY f.SECTION_A,
          Month(f.received_date),
          f.client_id,
          s.SALES_REP_NAME,
          s.REGION_NAME
```

**why would my left joins LIMIT my result set?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the fix is to add the conditions into the `on` clause rather than in the `where` clause:

```
FROM   MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV..F_ACCESSION_DAILY f
       LEFT JOIN salesdwh..TestPractices t
         ON F.CLIENT_ID = t.ClientID
       LEFT JOIN MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV..D_CLIENT d
         ON d.CLIENT_ID = f.CLIENT_ID and d.REC_ACTIVE_FLAG = 1
       LEFT JOIN MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV..D_SALES_HIERARCHY s
         ON s.SUB_TERRITORY_NBR = d.SUB_TERRITORY_NBR and s.REC_ACTIVE_FLAG = 1
```

Comment: what is the diff between doing it my way and your way? how are the results different?

Comment: when you pull the condition to the where you take away the left

Answer (score 4):

You are not just adding left outer joins, you are also adding filtering conditions:

```
and d.REC_ACTIVE_FLG=1
and s.REC_ACTIVE_FLG=1
```

This effectively turns your outer joins into inner joins. It also potentially filters out some records where `d` and/or `s` exist, but `REC_ACTIVE_FLG` don't equal `1`.

Comment: Would be better to explain that this will make the left joins work like inner joins.